# данные для ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Привет, после заполнения формы и нажатия на кнопки, ajax передает на сервер сириализованную форму:

```
data: { to:"checkin", data: $('#checkin').serialize() }
```

на сервер приходит строка в urlencode

```
 Array
    (
        [to] => checkin
        [data] => phone=111&email=222
    )
```

пробовал

```
data: { to:"checkin", $('#checkin').serialize() }
```

при этом ругается js

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

Как на сервере получить массив сериализованных данных?

```
 Array
        (
            [to] => checkin
            [data] => Array 
                             (
                                [phone] => 111
                                [email] => 222

                             )
        )
```

Comment: $.post( "test.php", $( "#checkin" ).serialize() ); и тогда в $_POST будут эти данные

Comment: мне туда нужно еще добавить один параметр

Comment: написал в ответе

Comment: `при этом ругается js` - надо угадать как ругается?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы передать данные как JSON надо использовать .serializeArray() https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/